# Simulating stage repositories with nexus3

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Nexus3, even the pro version,does not support staging repos, and I would find that feature useful.
Can I simulate it? for example, by creating those nexus3 groovy scripts that would copy the specified group id from the stage repository to the release repository, deleting data from stage repository afterwards. Also something to clean up staging repository. Would that be doable, possible and/or a good idea?

Comment: For what purpose exactly is staging really needed ? If you need it why not using a Nexus 2 ? Apart from that you have to use the commercial version of Nexus....

Comment: my ci server would deploy release artifacts on release builds. they can either be deployed immediately, or deployed to a staging repo in order to be able to somehow verify the release and then move it, or whatever.

Comment: I would just deploy the artifacts to the release repository and if those artifacts failing (finding bugs) create a new release. usually a release should be checked by running the unit tests and integration tests. If this will produce an release which contains bugs you need to improve/enhance you tests to make a new release which better than the release before (which has a different version number)...I really don't see a benefit in this scenario of having a staging repository...

Comment: well I plan to have both kinds of tests, although my experience in writing them is almost none, and this is a personal/home project so no one will help there.

Answer (score 1):

Staging, just like Winter, is coming.

Hang tight for a bit and you'll be able to use it in Nexus Repository 3.

Comment: not likely it will be in oss version. so I probably won't, unfortunatelty.

Comment: You are correct, this will be in Pro, however you'd mentioned that in your original question, hence the answer.

Comment: yeah, but part of the problem is I wouldn't be able to afford the pro version. so either I would not use stage repositories nor anything similar, or I would try to simulate their functionality if possible. Seems like the nexus scripts and api would make it quite possible to do such fancy things, as you actually get access to the whole nexus api, if I am not mistaken.